# Javascript IndexOf Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var fruits=["Apple", "Oranges", "Mutton", "Chicken"]

alert(fruits.indexOf("Mutton", 1));      // returns 2

alert("Blue Whale".indexOf("", 10));     // returns 10
```

**Syntax**

```
str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

An optional [fromIndex] lets you specify the position in which to begin the search (default is 0, or search entire array):

Then why the below code returns 2:

```
 alert(fruits.indexOf("Mutton", 1));
```

I think it should start the search from the first index that is 'Oranges' and display the result as 1. But it is displaying Result 2.

Also

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("", 10)
```

Here in "Blue Whale" string, the index value is upto 9. Then, why it is also accepting 10 and displaying the result as 10.

Comment: Note array.indexOf and string.indexOf are two _different_ methods that do _different_ things. They just sound similar if we treat strings like char arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the search starts at position x, the value returned will be the index of the element from the start of the array

In the case of `"Blue Whale".indexOf("", 10)` there are 10 characters and you are searching for an empty string which is found after the last char that is why 10 is returned

Comment: Then, what is the use of the optional Parameter FromIndex?

Comment: @Johnny Sample `"aba".indexOf('a',1) === 2`

Comment: @Johnny It is used if you want to skip some elements from being searched that is all

Comment: also you can find the index after the from index by subtracting the start index from the returned index

Answer (score 0):

Syntax

> str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])

so it start find from selected index but return index in collection, so index "Mutton" is 2, its returns

with case empty string returns string length

Comment: IndexOF second paramenter is Index and not Length?

Comment: yep, its index from which we begin to look, but if it greater then length of collection return legth, it work in case empty string and `string.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sample :

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
a.indexOf(1); // 0
a.indexOf(1, 1 /* = skip index 0 */); // 3
a.indexOf(1, 2 /* = skip indexes 0 and 1 */); // 3
```

I want to ignore the first occurence :

```
a.indexOf(1, a.indexOf(1) + 1); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf optional parameter does not return the position of a unique element in the array relative to the starting point, it is simply used to only search for the element in the array after that starting point.

For example, if you had this:

```
var fruits=["Mutton", "Apple", "Oranges", "Mutton", "Chicken"]
```

then

```
 alert(fruits.indexOf("Mutton", 0)); //Alerts 0
```

would return 0  because Mutton is at index 0, however if you start the search from index 1 instead, it's already past Mutton so won't see it, and will instead find the first entry of Mutton after index 1, which is 3 now:

```
 alert(fruits.indexOf("Mutton", 3)); //Alerts 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zKrzu/

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set the start position to 10 and search for "nothing".

Had your start position still been 10 and the string you searched for been example "e" it would return -1

Syntax

```
string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)
```